# Scala project - API to access tweets for posted for past 1,2,or 3 days?

Tags: scala, api, twitter, spark-streaming

I realize twitterutils.createstream is used to access the tweets in real time.

But If i need to access the tweets posted in the past 24 hours or 2 days  for scala project,which api do I need to use to access those tweets?

Any help regarding this query is appreciated.

Thank you,

Comment: What have you already tried? Show your efforts/code

Comment: Check twitter4j